# php code "<?=" in js format

Tags: php, javascript

This JavaScript code was in a PHP file, and I need to put this JS code into a `.js` file.

```js
<script>
  $j(".fresh").click(function(){
    $j(this).html('<span><?php echo $this->lang_arr['my_new_func']; ?></span>');

    $j.post(  "<?= site_url('website/func_resh') ?>",
              { id          : "<?= $webfun_one_arr[id] ?>",
                website_id  : "<?= $web_one_arr[id] ?>"
              }
    );
  })
</script>
```

I know this code `<?php echo $this->lang_arr['my_new_func']; ?>` in the JavaScript format is `{$this->lang_arr['my_new_func'];}`

But I don't know how I change `<?= site_url('website/func_resh') ?>` and `<?= $webfun_one_arr[id] ?>` into JS format.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you trying to generate a .js file with a PHP script, or are you trying to port a PHP script into JavaScript?

Comment: well that depends what he php function site_url() does.

Comment: @Justin the js code is in the php file, I'm trying to put them into a seperate .js file

Comment: Is this js file that has php in it included via a `<script src=` tag?

Comment: @ctcherry yes, so I need to remove the php label from the js file to make the js work

Comment: I suggest following the answer Ignacio left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolating PHP and JavaScript is a big can of worms that you should avoid opening. IMO the best way to deal with this is to use PHP to output a JSON object, [which it has built-in support for](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php), and then use the object in your JavaScript. This way you only have to put one tiny snippet of PHP in a `<script>` tag and you don't have to try to make the server parse `.js` files as PHP. Something like this:

In your PHP:

```php
<?php $my_vals = array(
        'myNewFunc'     => $this->lang_arr['my_new_func'],
        'postUrl'       => site_url('website/func_resh'),
        'postId'        => $webfun_one_arr['id'],
        'postWebsiteId' => $web_one_arr['id']
      );
?>
<script>
  $j.getScript('/path/to/your_script.js', function() {
    myFunc(<%= json_encode($my_vals); %>); // turns your PHP array into a
  });                                      // JavaScript object automatically
</script>
```

Then, in `your_script.js`:

```
// Look, Ma, no PHP!
function myFunc(someJson) {
  $j(".fresh").click(function(){
    $j(this).html('<span>' + someJson.myNewFunc + '</span>');

    $j.post( someJson.postUrl,
      { id          : someJson.postId,
        website_id  : someJson.postWebsiteId
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't. Make it a `.js.php` file that returns a content type of `text/javascript`, and includes the other relevant PHP scripts.

Comment: How do I "include" the php script? What is the code? I just don't know how to quote it in js=_=

Comment: You include with [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and the like. You don't do it in JavaScript, you do it in PHP and emit JavaScript.